# How do you use extension methods in Web form data-binding expressions?

Tags: data-binding, webforms, extension-methods

Has anyone successfully used extension methods in data-binding expressions?

Say I have an extension method called "GetName" attached to "MyClass".

In the code behind, I have verified this works:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();   
MyClass.GetName();
```

However, in a Web form, I try this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="My.Namespace" %>
```

Then, in the ItemTemplate of a Repeater:

```
<%# ((MyClass)Container.DataItem).GetName() %>
```

Visual Studio is cool with this, Intellisense agrees with everything, and the project builds.  But when I run it, I get:

> Compilation Error
>   'My.Namespace.MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'GetName'

So, the code-behind will accept the extension method, but not the Web form.  I suspect it's a name-spacing issue, but I've imported the same namespace in both places.

Comment: I finally found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/486913/2119731

Answer (score 4):

The databinding syntax in aspx/ascx files is notoriously picky. There is a certain amount of parsing that goes on, in particular in this binding area. Look at this example:

This works:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", DataBinder.Eval("Foo")) %>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Bind("Foo")) %>
```

Why? Because while DataBinder.Eval is a real method, Bind is not. Yes, really, it's just a token recognized by the expression binder/parser - it's not actually compiled. I think DataBinder.Eval is probably special-cased for compatibility with ASP.NET 1.1/1.0.

Just to complete the example, the correct way to bind the above expression is to use:

```
<%# Bind("Foo", "{0:C}") %>
```

Hope this helps,

**Clarification Edit:** The C# compiler understands extension methods. The asp.net expression parser does not.

Comment: While this information might be useful to some people, it really doesn't address the actual question. That said, I also don't know the answer.

Comment: @SynBiotik I think the message to take away from my answer is that the compiler understands extension methods, but the asp.net page parser / expression binder does not. Since the syntax is just syntactic sugar for the parser, the compiler will never see it. TL;DR: It is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

If you're binding to a collection and want to leverage the strongly typed class MyClass, you can perform the extension in a function in codebehind.

your repeater can use

```
<%# GetObjectName((MyClass)Container.DataItem) %>
```

Your CodeBehind will have:

```
protected string GetObjectName(MyClass obJect)
    {
        return obJect.GetName();
    }
```

Don't forget to import the namespace of your extension module.